CORS Error When Making Fetch Request from localhost:3000 to 127.0.0.1:5000
I'm developing a chatbot using a Flask backend and a React frontend. My frontend runs on http://localhost:3000 and the backend API is on http://127.0.0.1:5000. When I send input to the chatbot via a fetch request to the /predict endpoint, I receive a CORS error. The complete error message is:
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Here's the fetch request in my React application:
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Hi" })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

The Flask backend is supposed to handle the request and respond with a message generated by the chatbot model. Here's the relevant backend code in chat.py:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import random
import json
import torch
from model import NeuralNet
from nltk_utils import bag_of_words, tokenize

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)  # Enable CORS for all domains

# Chatbot model initialization...

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    sentence = request.json['message']
    response = get_response(sentence)
    return jsonify({"response": response})

def get_response(msg):
    # Processing the message through the chatbot model...
    
    return "Response based on model prediction..."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)

Despite using flask_cors to enable CORS for all domains, the preflight request seems to fail. How can I resolve this issue to allow CORS requests from my frontend to my backend, ensuring the chatbot can receive and respond to messages?
Additional Information:

Backend server: Flask, with CORS set up using flask_cors.
Frontend: React app running locally.
Both components run on different ports on localhost.
The chatbot model involves PyTorch for processing and responding to user inputs.


Self duplicate of CORS policy error when fetching POST request in Flask app from React frontend

This seems to be your 3rd reposted question. And every time you got the same (wrong) answer.

And you haven't responded to my comment on your previous question. What debugging did you do? If the response status isn't "ok", then what is it? My guess is 500.

You seem to have not set any cors header.
When you use a fetch you need to confige your acces control header for the content-type.
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
CORS(app)

If that doesn't help, you can even put this header right on your response:
response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")


Access-Control-Allow-Headers (plural).

Did you actually read the error message? It has nothing to do with the header.
